# Getting Facebook Cover Photo URL in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

When using Facebook's graph explorer graph paths I was able to get the user's cover photo URL using:

```
        connection.add(GraphRequest(graphPath: "/me/albums")) { httpResponse, result in ...
```

then finding the id with the name: "Cover Photos" and using the graph request:

```
    connection.add(GraphRequest(graphPath: ("/" + id + "/photos"))) { httpResponse, result in
```

then taking the first and most recent id from the Cover Photos album

then finally use the graph request:

```
        connection.add(GraphRequest(graphPath: ("/" + id + "/picture"))) { httpResponse, result in
```

to get the URL of the cover photo.

However, when performing the final graph request, I get the error:

```
UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Response is a non-text MIME type; endpoints that return images and other binary data should be fetched using NSURLRequest and NSURLSession}
```

I haven't been able to use NSURLRequest nor NSURLSession to get the URL. To be clear, when using "/" + id + "/picture" in the Facebook Graph Explorer, I was able to get the cover photo URL. However, it does not work with iOS. I believe I have the correct permissions in:

```
        let loginButton = LoginButton(readPermissions: [ .publicProfile, .userPhotos ])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    func findCoverPhotoPicture(id: String) {
    print("find cover url", id)
    print("https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture")

    let imgURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture"
    do {
        let covImg: UIImage = try UIImage(data: Data(contentsOf: URL(string: imgURL)!))!
        self.picView.image = covImg
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```